# HTML Template - XML - HTML

Tags: html, xml

I'm working on a mailer system where I'm required to replace variables in html template with actual values in our database. Earlier, I was getting a plain HTML template where I was required to overwrite the variable's actual value from database to the template itself. However, I was not comfortable with it. I made the following suggestion that instead of whole HTML template, pass XML containing the attributes which we seek to replace with actual values from database(sort of RSS). Now I am finding a way to put the actual values found from the database to the original template. Let us take an example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div var="toxml">
      <li>
        PROFILEID(This will be a number)
        NAME
        AGE(etc.)
      </li>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The XML which will be generated out of this will be

```
<PROFILEID val="Number">
  <NAME></NAME>
  <AGE></AGE>
</PROFILEID>
```

Now I will stuff in the values from database in this xml only(XML parsing tools are available for php).

Now my question is, how can I put the stuffed values in the XML back to the HTML template from which it came?

Comment: Ankit - your question is not very clear. Just that you mentioned PHP somewhere, I'm assuming it's a web application. PHP (or any web server language) is ment for these kind of tasks - Read values from database and create dynamic HTML elements. Please can you add more details?

Comment: @sreehari Yes it is a web application only. Let me try to explain it a bit more. I want to replace variables in an HTML templalate. Instead of reading whole HTML (as it can be very long), I'm generating an XML from the same HTML based on certain tags and attributes. I can stuff the XML with my values, but I need to find a way to stuff the stuffed XML into the same HTML template from which my XML file was generated.

Comment: How are you generating the XML without reading the whole HTML content? The question is too specific to a particular requirement. Does not qualify to be asked here.

Comment: the var tag/attribute can be used. My bad, in haste i wrote. Yes full HTML is read to generate XML. I've generated the xml from html. And moreover, i think we can ask questions even if it's to specific.

Comment: that's not correct. You need to show what you've already done to solve this problem. This is not a question that others would be benefited with. This is very specific to a business requirement of yours. You are asking for someone to write source code for you.